# How to include date and time column in log4j html report

Tags: java, logging, log4j

I want to include the date and time column in my `log4j` html report or at least in the file name.

Today it is saved like this:

> HTMLlog.html

, I would like it to be like this

> HTMLlog_dd-MM-yyyy.html

It would be even better if this information was inside the report, for the end user.

**My log4j-html.properties:**

```
# Define the root logger with file appender
log4j.rootLogger = DEBUG, HTML

    # Define the file appender
    log4j.appender.HTML=org.apache.log4j.FileAppender
    log4j.appender.HTML.File=tools/HTMLlog.html

    # Define the html layout for file appender
    log4j.appender.HTML.layout=org.apache.log4j.HTMLLayout
    log4j.appender.HTML.layout.Title=Compra Catalogo Sem Preco
    log4j.appender.HTML.layout.LocationInfo=true
    log4j.appender.HTML.Threshold=DEBUG
```

**My version:**

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.13.2</version>
        </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

**AS-IS**

```
log4j.appender.HTML.File=tools/HTMLlog.html
```

**TO-BE**

```
log4j.appender.HTML.File=tools/HTMLlog_%d{MM-dd-yyyy}.html
```

Comment: I had already tried this and tried again, the file has this nomenclature: HTMLlog_% d {MM-dd-yyyy} .html, when in fact I would like it to be HTMLlog_20200511.html

Comment: @PauloRoberto Did you insert white space between '%' and 'd', 'd' and '{', '}', '.'? I think you should use the name without white spaces like 'HTMLlog_%d{MM-dd-yyyy}.html'

Comment: It was a mistake when posting, but the code is out of space.